# "According to our discussion, is that correct I DO this part?" is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality

The whole sentence is here:

Since this coming Sunday is the first day of March, our children need new TWA schedules, according to our discussion, is that correct I DO this part?

Can I write this sentence like that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you break your sentence into two and reword it for clarity:

> Since this coming Sunday is the first day of March, our children need
>   new TWA schedules. According to our discussion, providing these is my
>   responsibility, right?

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. Actually, it is not really my responsibility. we shared some opinions and we need someone to do this part. I said I can provide TWA schedules, but we didn't have time to finalize before leaving. So I am sending an email to friends to make sure is it really me to do these.